# Understanding Ember code to findSection from a list

Tags: javascript, ember.js

In my Ember app, I have the following code which finds a section (actually mapped to an Ember component) from a list of sections. I am trying to understand this line:

> return e.id === sectionId;

I wanted to understand what it is actually trying to match and what it actually returns from the grep (and ultimately from the function).

```
findSection: function(sections, sectionId) {
    var result = $.grep(sections, function(e){
        if (!Ember.isEmpty(e)){
            return e.id === sectionId;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
    return result[0];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

grep in jquery Finds the elements of an array which satisfy a filter function. The original array is not affected.

grep function in jquery have callback function (`function(e)`) in array list (`sections`) that each element is `e` in `sections` array.

this line compares `e.id` with `sectionId` and return true or false.

Read more about grep on http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/